# How to add a submodule in Gitlab into my local repository

Tags: git, gitlab, git-submodules

I'm a beginner and I'd been trying to resolve this problem for hours.

If there's a submodule that appears in my Gitlab repository, and I want to add it into my local repository. What should be the command to do this?

For example, my Gitlab repo URL is below, `trees` folder is a new submodule that doesn't appear on my local repo:

https://gitlab.com/my_components/trees.git

Would the solution be to pull or clone that specific submodule so that they're synced?

Below in the command line. I went into the specific path and use the following command (?):

```
\docs\my_components> git clone https://gitlab.com/my_components/trees.git
```

Or going above one level:

```
\docs>git submodule update https://gitlab.com/my_components.git
```

Although this last one will update the whole parent folder, which I'm not looking for since it will take hours (it has thousands of components).

I just need to sync a specific submodule, not the whole parent folder.

Comment: `cd my_components; git submodule update trees` ?

Comment: @ndrwnaguib, why not add https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75462740/how-to-add-a-submodule-in-gitlab-into-my-local-repository#comment133147781_75462740 as an answer?

Comment: @tadm123 did the commands in my comment work for you back then?